# How to search multivalued field in Solr

Tags: solr

I want a Solr query on a multivalued field, and i want as a result all documents that have only a specific value.

Example :

*my_field:[1,0]

my_field:[1,1]

my_field:[0,0]

my_field:[-1,0]*

i want to search all documents that have the value **-1**

This is the error i get

```
{
responseHeader: {
status: 400,
QTime: 1,
params: {
fl: "my_field_txt",
indent: "true",
q: "*:*",
wt: "json",
fq: [
"category:PDV",
"my_field_txt:-1"
]
}
},
error: {
msg: "org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse 'my_field_txt:-1': Encountered " "-" "- "" at line 1, column 37.
Was expecting one of:
    <BAREOPER> ...
    "(" ...
    "*" ...
    <QUOTED> ...
    <TERM> ...
    <PREFIXTERM> ...
    <WILDTERM> ...
    <REGEXPTERM> ...
    "[" ...
    "{" ...
    <LPARAMS> ...
    <NUMBER> ...
    ",
code: 400
}
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> q=fieldname:"querystring"

q=my_field:-1

Comment: If you indexed sample docs inside exampledocs folder of solr instance. then try this URL  http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=cat:"connector"&wt=json&indent=true